# Java format Date to UTC sometimes produce '????-??-??T??:??:??.???Z'

Tags: c#, android, simpledateformat, android-ksoap2, date

In our Android application, we have a util method for formatting a date to UTC:

```
 static String formatToUTC(Date date) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        return dateFormat.format(date).replace(" ", "T") + "Z";
    }
```

what sometimes produce the value:

> ????-??-??T??:??:??.???Z

To fix the issue we should reproduce it first, but we can't reproduce the behavior.
We were trying different Locales and pass an invalid new Date() from Long.Max_VALUE, Long.MIN_VALUE.

The question is:
What can be a reason for this issue?

Thanks in advance!

**Edited:**

The date is Android app generated in two ways:

1. `new Date();`
2. `new Date(longValue)`

The date comes from a worldwide.

**Edited 2:**

The issue appears on a server side (written on a **c#**).

We use [the Ksoap2 for Android](https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android) to interact with a server and it fails sometimes trying to convert **????-??-??T??:??:??.???Z** to a DateTime object.
But main time everything is good.

Comment: Offtop: instead of magic char replacement and concatenation just use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` pattern.

Comment: Where is the garbled string confirmed (e.g., UI level, inside formatToUTC via debugger, etc.)? If there are other methods that take the return value of formatToUTC(Date date) and manipulate/use it, those might be responsible for encoding errors.

Comment: Maybe a clue as to where the `Date` is coming from might give a little more insight. User input?  Returned from a database (guaranteed format?)?  Does the date come from a single region or world wide? Android app generated? If app generated add that code to your question.

Comment: @Barns I have added answers to the edited question.

Comment: Indeed that is odd behavior. I have tried to generate dates in a loop with `new Date(longValue)` -- even improbable values -- and I cannot duplicate the strange result. Oleg provided a pattern that will allow you to get rid of the `replace()` method. About the only thing you can do is try to catch the unexpected value and log it.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Perhaps check the source code for the `SimpleDateFormat` code to look for a string literal of the Question Mark character. But easier just to replace these awful classes with *java.time*, and move on.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for your suggestions, but unfortunately we cant use 3th part libraries in our project.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now().
       .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLISECONDS ) ;
       .toString()
```

> 2018-01-23T01:23:45.123Z

## Thread-safety issue?

That is bizarre behavior I have not heard of. My first guess is a threading problem. The legacy date-time classes are *not* thread-safe. Their replacements, the *java.time* classes, are entirely thread-safe.

## java.time

You could replace those troublesome old legacy classes. They were supplanted years ago in Java by the modern *java.time* classes. For Android, see bullets below.

### `Instant`

The `java.util.Date` class was replaced by `java.time.Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

If you want only milliseconds, you can truncate any microseconds or nanoseconds that may be present in your `Instant`.

```
Instant instantTruncated = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLISECONDS ) ;
```

### ISO 8601

Your desired output format is defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2018-01-23T01:23:45.123Z

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

To help you figure out the issue I would check if the returned String contains any question marks in it, and if it does then throw an Exception. Set a breaker point in your exception and it should let you see exactly which value is breaking your date.

Something along the lines of:

```
static String formatToUTC(Date date) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String temp = dateFormat.format(date).replace(" ", "T") + "Z"

    if (temp.contains("?"))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date");  //set a breakpoint here

    return temp;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Good suggestion if `java.time` is out of bounds. Even better, include the value of `date.getTime()` in the exception message. I would also insert the `if` statement both before and after `replace` and concatenation, with different messages, so as to rule out that one of those string operations is causing the trouble.